# kotlin: cannot get validation api's annotation

Tags: annotations, kotlin

==========UPDATE==========

when i change the annotation to @get:NotNull , @get:Min and @get:Max, the hibernate-validator can read these annotations success.

But what i still want to know is:

**why the validation-api's annotation, such as @NotNull , @Min and @Max cannot be used on data class's members directly, while JPA's annotations can be????**

==========Bellow is the origin question===========

when i tried to use validation-api's annotation on data class, the Validator class (from hibernate-validator) cannot get the annotations, so the validation failed.

i wrote a test case, which include 3 data classes:

- 1st one use JPA annotation @Column and @Id, which can be read successfully by test case.
- 2nd one use validation-api annotation @NotEmpty, @Min,@Max on members, these annotation cannot be read by test case
- 3rd one use validation-api annotation @get:NotEmpty, @get:Min, @get:Max, the test case cannot read these annotation.

The target and retention of @Column , @NotNull, @Min and @Max are all:
  RUNTIME and FIELD

So, what happened in the behind? how can i use the validation annotations properly?

here is the test case:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty
import org.junit.Test
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.validation.constraints.Max
import javax.validation.constraints.Min
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaField
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaMethod

class KotlinFeatureTest2 {
    @Test
    fun test_get_annotation() {
        // can get field's annotation for BeanUseJPAAnnotation success
        println("Getting field annotations for BeanUseJPAAnnotation :")
        BeanUseJPAAnnotation::class.members.forEach {
            if (it is KProperty) {
                val field = it.javaField
                println("${field?.name}'s annotations:")
                field?.annotations?.forEachIndexed { i, an ->
                    println("        $i is: $an")
                }
            }
        }

        println("--------------------")
        println("Getting field annotations for BeanUseValidationAnnotation :")
        // CANT get field's annotation for BeanUseJPAAnnotation success
        BeanUseValidationAnnotation::class.members.forEach {
            if (it is KProperty) {
                val field = it.javaField
                println("${field?.name}'s annotations:")
                field?.annotations?.forEachIndexed { i, an ->
                    println("        $i is: $an")
                }
            }
        }

        println("--------------------")
        println("Getting field annotations for BeanUseValidationAnnotationOnMethod :")
        // CANT get field's annotation for BeanUseJPAAnnotation success
        BeanUseValidationAnnotationOnMethod::class.members.forEach {
            if (it is KFunction) {
                val method = it.javaMethod
                println("${method?.name}'s annotations: ")
                method?.annotations?.forEachIndexed { i, an ->
                    println("        $i is: $an")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

data class BeanUseJPAAnnotation(
        @Column(name = "id") @Id val id: String,
        @Column(name = "user_name") val name: String)

data class BeanUseValidationAnnotation(
        @NotEmpty(message = "name can not be empty")
        val name: String,

        @Min(value = 1)
        @Max(value = 100)
        val age: Int
)

data class BeanUseValidationAnnotationOnMethod(
        @get:NotEmpty(message = "name can not be empty")
        val name: String,

        @get:Min(value = 1)
        @get:Max(value = 100)
        val age: Int)
```

and here are the output of this test case:

```
Getting field annotations for BeanUseJPAAnnotation :
id's annotations:
    0 is: @javax.persistence.Column(nullable=true, unique=false, precision=0, name=id, length=255, scale=0, updatable=true, columnDefinition=, table=, insertable=true)
    1 is: @javax.persistence.Id()
name's annotations:
    0 is: @javax.persistence.Column(nullable=true, unique=false, precision=0, name=user_name, length=255, scale=0, updatable=true, columnDefinition=, table=, insertable=true)
--------------------
Getting field annotations for BeanUseValidationAnnotation :
age's annotations:
name's annotations:
--------------------
Getting field annotations for BeanUseValidationAnnotationOnMethod :
component1's annotations: 
component2's annotations: 
copy's annotations: 
equals's annotations: 
hashCode's annotations: 
toString's annotations:
```

Comment: UPDATE: when i change the annotation to "@get:NotNull" , "@get:Min" and "@get:Max", the hibernate-validator can read these annotations success. But what i still want to know is: why the validation-api's annotation, such as "@NotNull" , "@Min" and "@Max" cannot be used on data class's members directly, while JPA's annotations can be????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the signature part of [`javax.persistence.Column`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/persistence/Column.java#L47):

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD}) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Column {
```

On the contrary here's the same part of [`javax.validation.constraints.Min`](https://github.com/beanvalidation/beanvalidation-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/validation/constraints/Min.java#L54):

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(List.class)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface Min {
```

As you can see the JPA Persistence annotations target `METHOD` and `FIELD` hence Kotlin emits them on a `FIELD` level. However the validators API annotations target more constructs, the `PARAMETER` in particular. Given that when generating annotations for constructor declared properties Kotlin compiler chooses to annotate **parameters only**. The `BeanUseValidationAnnotation` constructor signature equivalent in Java would look like:

```
public BeanUseValidationAnnotation(@NotEmpty(message = "name can not be empty") @NotNull String name, @Min(1L) @Max(100L) int age) {
```

This behavior is stated [in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets):

> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according
>   to the `@Target` annotation of the annotation being used. If there are
>   multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the
>   following list is used:
>
> - `param`
> - `property`
> - `field`

Comment: thanks for your great explanation which makes things clear ~